# Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} F(x) = 1 $

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Let F be its cumulative distribution function: $F(x) = P(X ≤ x)$ for all $x$ in $R$.

> a) Use countable additivity to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(n) = 1$. Here $n$ runs to $\infty$ through the integers. Be explicit about the countable collection of pairwise disjoint sets.

In this case I took $ (-∞, 0], (n-1,n] $.

> (b) Use part (a) to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1 $. Here $ x $ is a continuous variable, not just an integer.

I was wondering how to do (b) by using part (a)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So, you know that the sequence $F(1), F(2), \dots, F(n), \dots$ converges to $1$.

You want to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$. If you want to use the convergence of the above sequence, you will somehow have to relate $F(x)$ to $F(n)$.

Hint: Suppose $x \geq y$, then what can you say about $F(x)$ and $F(y)$? How can you use this with a certain $x$ and one or more integers?

Comment: @ Harry,  that implies   F(x)>F(y) or F(x)=F(y). Isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, $x \geq y$ implies $F(x) \geq F(y)$. How can you use this with $x$ an some integer (related to $x$)? Does this help you prove the limit?

Comment: that means we gonna use for every x there is an integer n greater or equal to x.

Comment: That is certainly true. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: so, when n goes to infinity then x also goes to infinity. we can use part  (a) here, right?

Comment: That is the correct intuition behind this exercise. However, I think it would be instructive to try and write out a formal proof.

Comment: Could  you please, provide  some lines formal proof for me.

Comment: Let $x$ be some real number. By what you just said, $F(x) \geq F(\lfloor x \rfloor)$. Hence, if the limit exists, $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) \geq \lim_{x \to \infty} F(\lfloor x \rfloor) = 1$, as this last limit is over the integers only.
Similarly, $x \leq \lceil x \rceil$, thus ... (finish this yourself). What can you conclude about the limit?